# Authenticate the SharePoint 2013 Foundation site into the android application

Tags: android, rest, mobile, sharepoint-2013, phonegap-build

I have a site in SharePoint Foundation 2013 which is public (within organisation domain - no network boundary). Now I want to make a mobile app for this site. Below are the details:

I need to develop a android application to show the SharePoint List Items/Data, using the SharePoint 2013 Rest API. But The problem is of authentication. I'm using Windows NTLM Claim based authentication in the SharePoint foundation 2013.

How can I authenticate the SharePoint site inside the android application and get the SharePoint data and displays it in the android app?

I am using Phonegap to develope the mobile app

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NTLM Authentication library on Android.

Check out this: http://danhounshell.com/blog/android-using-ntlm-authentication-with-httpclient/

You can use the JAR available at this location to make HTTP requests with NTLM:

http://jcifs.samba.org/